# Pandas: add columns to multiindex for any depht of index levels

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add columns with missing levels (index=1) to each parent level (index = 0) to a dataframe. For a simple dataframe this works quite nicely

```
index = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']]
cols = [['AC', 'AC', 'BC', 'DC', 'CC'], ['ac', 'aac', 'bc', 'ac', 'bc']]
data = np.random.random((4, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=cols)
df.columns.names = ['col_name_0', 'col_name_1']
```

The dataframe:

```
col_name_0        AC                  BC        DC        CC
col_name_1        ac       aac        bc        ac        bc
A a         0.169402  0.899434  0.644941  0.330402  0.805702
B b         0.933743  0.994497  0.060507  0.609129  0.545999
C a         0.064937  0.686350  0.740594  0.985218  0.717699
D b         0.151031  0.932294  0.948751  0.538251  0.085700
```

The processing step:

```
feature_index = [index for index, item in enumerate(df.columns.names) if item == 'col_name_1'][0]
all_features = df.columns.levels[feature_index].to_list()

for idx, item in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    features = item.columns.get_level_values(1).to_list()
    missing = list(set(all_features) - set(features))
    for m_item in missing:
        df[idx, m_item] = np.nan * np.ones(df.shape[0])
```

The processed df:

```
col_name_0        AC                BC      ...  CC            DC              
col_name_1       aac        ac  bc aac  ac  ...  ac        bc aac        ac  bc
A a         0.561247  0.353270 NaN NaN NaN  ... NaN  0.733714 NaN  0.343174   NaN
B b         0.699053  0.696892 NaN NaN NaN  ... NaN  0.144768 NaN  0.267141 NaN
C a         0.624581  0.064629 NaN NaN NaN  ... NaN  0.856559 NaN  0.772735 NaN
D b         0.563903  0.192823 NaN NaN NaN  ... NaN  0.071497 NaN  0.000361 NaN
```

But for a dataframe with multiple column levels like the one below, the method fails:

```
index = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']]
cols = [['AC', 'AC', 'BC', 'DC', 'CC'], ['ac', 'aac', 'bc', 'ac', 'bc'], ['Xc', 'Xc', 'Xc', 'Xc', 'Xc']]
data = np.random.random((4, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=cols)
df.columns.names = ['col_name_0', 'col_name_1', 'col_name_2']
```

The original dataframe:

```
col_name_0        AC                  BC        DC        CC
col_name_1        ac       aac        bc        ac        bc
col_name_2        Xc        Xc        Xc        Xc        Xc
A a         0.317022  0.700635  0.305712  0.934382  0.315501
B b         0.601277  0.726890  0.737907  0.571935  0.716260
C a         0.679046  0.314987  0.846560  0.962516  0.770071
D b         0.124029  0.626421  0.967531  0.193875  0.395897
```

The processings steps:

```
feature_index = [index for index, item in enumerate(df.columns.names) if item == 'col_name_1'][0]
all_features = df.columns.levels[feature_index].to_list()

for idx, item in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    features = item.columns.get_level_values(1).to_list()
    missing = list(set(all_features) - set(features))
    for m_item in missing:
        df[idx, m_item] = np.nan * np.ones(df.shape[0])
```

The error message:

`ValueError: Item must have length equal to number of levels.`

Any ideas how I could make my approach more generic to accept any column levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just using `stack` and `unstack`

```
out = df.stack(level = 1).unstack().swaplevel(1, 2, axis = 1)
```

Comment: @Moritz have you original df , apply above method

Comment: I asked a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316076/pandas-unstack-stack-to-fill-missing-features-with-nans Maybe you find that interesting? I would highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `reindex`:

```
full_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels,
                                       names=df.columns.names)
df.reindex(full_cols, axis=1)
```

Comment: Only one thing , `reindex` method will recover all missing level(if the level 3 do not need recover cross the level) , however still a nice solution